# PyQt5 Attribute Error: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'setLayout'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

There seems to be an attribute error when I run my code. Specifically, the error I encounter is:

```
AttributeError: 'GUI' object has no attribute 'setLayout'
```

The code I'm currently using:

```
class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        review = QtWidgets.QLabel('Review')
        reviewEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        grid.addWidget(review, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,350,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sentiment Analysis')
        self.show()
```

Comment: This is how I imported the modules: from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtWidgets,QtCore

Comment: Your ``GUI`` class inherits ``object``. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are trying to call ``setLayout`` on ``self`` -- or ``object``. Don't you need ``MainWindow`` or another Qt parent/widget?

Answer (score 3):

You get an attribute error because neither your class nor `object` defines the methods you try to access through `self`. You need to inherit these from a `Qt` class that defines them. For example, inheriting from `QWidget`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class GUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
     ...
```

will makes these available for your class. Substitute the appropriate `PyQt` base class for your use case to get the functionality.

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the help